# Drupal Settings file does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, content-management-system

I'm trying to set up a fresh install of drupal on on linux box and I'm getting the error:

Settings file   The settings file does not exist.
The Drupal installer requires that you create a settings file as part of the installation process. Copy the ./sites/default/default.settings.php file to ./sites/default/settings.php. More details about installing Drupal are available in INSTALL.txt.

I have set the permissions for the settings.php file but it is still doing it. sites,default and files all have 777 permissions but it still won't work. I have both the default.settings.php and settings.php in the default folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep in mind some things:

- Your web server has to have the permission to run your code. If you are using Ubuntu, it would be better if you give www-data.www-data (user and group) permission to sites/default folder
- To give 777 to files is dangerous because someone else can read this sensible file
- Remember that all folders, including your Drupal root folder has to be readable, which means it has to have some thing like 755 permission.

Most time, this problem is related to the user running the web server and files.

Answer (score 1):

Change back the `settings.php` permission.change **`settings.php permission to 755`**. (`read only, to make protected`)

Step by step:

1. `Copy file default.settings.php to settings.php (do not rename). Now you have both files.`
2. `Change file permission settings.php to read/write with chmod 644 settings.php`
3. `Continue the installation..`
4. `After all installation finished, change file permission settings.php to read-only with chmod 755 settings.php`

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that by this:

```
chown -Rv apache:apache /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

go to the directory that contain default.settings.php & settings.php files then, right click on each one then click on Get Info then scroll down until you see the permission of that file, make sure it's 'read & write' [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7wV2.png)